# Inserting values of one column of a table into different columns of another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a ***table A with 2 columns*** with Group and **Age**. I need to `insert` the only 3 entries in the age column to a different table B which has columns Age 1, age 2, age 3. How can I do that.

`INSERT INTO B (Age1, Age 2, Age 3)`
`Values/ select .....`

```
TABLE A
#GROUP | AGE
#AGE1    23
#AGE2     25
AGE3     29

TABLE B
#(ID | AGE1 | AGE2 | AGE3)
#(1    --      --     ---)
```

CATCH: I cannot hard code in this case. is there any way of using cursors in dynamic sql to get this done

Comment: What do you mean by cannot hard code? Will table A always have groups of 3 rows i.e. Age 1,2,3 for ID 1, then 3 for ID 2 and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I figured out the solution. All I needed to do is get both the columns in a COMMA separated varchar variable. Then pass the variables in a dynamic sql in the insert values.

```
Insert into table B
('+@rowsincolumn1+')
values('+rowsincolumn2+')
```

Make sure you insert Single quotes in your varchar variable after every value to make it run in the dyn sql.